# How block ads from Asp .Net MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

My Asp .net MVC 4 website, when opening pages in googlechrome showing advertisements, how can I avoid this? so any of my website user shouldn't irritate with this.

Comment: in where display advertisement?

Comment: Are you sure it is not being generated from your browser, by a plugin? I don't see how a site you created can just adopt adverts without your consent.

Comment: yup, sounds like you have an aggressive plugin or possibly malware on your machine.